# Android cursor get column index using string

Tags: android, cursor

When I do `cursor.getColumnIndex(Database._F_A3)` this works as expected.

But if I do this

```
String dbColumn = "Database._F_A3";
cursor.getColumnIndex(dbColumn );
```

it gives error.

I believe that this is because `getColumnIndex()` manages whatever is inside the parenthesis as the string to search in the columns.

Is there any way to do what I want?

favolas

Comment: What is Database in Database._F_A3 ?

Comment: Database is my SQLite database and _F_A3 is one of the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String dbColumn = "Database._F_A3";
cursor.getColumnIndex(dbColumn );
```

calling above is completely wrong, because it changes the the name that you declared as static in Database class,

suppose you declared in your Database class as,

```
public static String _F_A3 = "something";
```

and now if you call,

```
String dbColumn = "Database._F_A3";
cursor.getColumnIndex(dbColumn );  // it means you are using Database._F_A3 
                 // as column name which doesn't exist instead of "something"
```

So, better try using

```
String dbColumn = Database._F_A3;  // without quotes
cursor.getColumnIndex(dbColumn );
```

Comment: Thanks Lalit. The purpose of this is that I have many columns with the prefix _F_A? being the ? something. Somethimes I want to use `Database._F_A3` and others, for example, `Database._F_A2356`. This way I would do a string concat with `Database._F_A` plus the string with the rest of the column name

Comment: Better is to use `Database._F_A3` constant only.

Comment: OK. Will have to put a ton of `if - else` clause then